# How to get the location of installed Python package into the shell

Tags: python, docker-compose

I want my users to be able to reference a file in my python package (specifically a docker-compose.yml file) directly from the shell.

I couldnt find a way to get *only* the location from `pip show` (and grep-ing out "location" from its output feels ugly), so my current (somewhat verbose) solution is:

```
docker compose -f $(python3 -c "import locust_plugins; print(locust_plugins.__path__[0])")/timescale/docker-compose.yml up
```

Is there a better way?

Edit: I solved it by installing a wrapper command I call `locust-compose` as part of the package. Not perfect, but it gets the job done:

```
#!/bin/bash
module_location=$(python3 -c "import locust_plugins; print(locust_plugins.__path__[0])")
set -x
docker compose -f $module_location/timescale/docker-compose.yml "$@"
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the support you need for this is in the core [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/) suite.

First of all, you need to make sure the [data file is included in your package](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html).  In a `setup.cfg` file you can write:

```
[options.package_data]
timescale = docker-compose.yml
```

Now if you `pip install .` or `pip wheel`, that will include the Compose file as part of the Python package.

Next, you can retrieve this in Python code using the [`ResourceManager` API](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resourcemanager-api):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# timescale/compose_path.py

import pkg_resources

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('timescale', 'docker-compose.yml'))
```

And finally, you can take that script and make it a setuptools [entry point script](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) (as distinct from the similarly-named Docker concept), so that you can just run it as a single command.

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts=
  timescale_compose_path = timescale:compose_path
```

Again, if you `pip install .` into a virtual environment, you should be able to run `timescale_compose_path` and get the path name out.

Having done all of those steps, you can finally run a simpler

```sh
docker-compose -f $(timescale_compose_path) up
```

Comment: Nice! I already had the first parts down (although I use MANIFEST.in to include the file in my package). I dont want to force my users to run virtualenv, so unfortunately I dont think I can use your approach.

Comment: Or wait, maybe your solution doesnt really require virtualenv? If so, it is very similar to my solution, and perhaps nicer even. Either way, both of our solutions are more workarounds of what I feel (wish) had a simpler solution.

Comment: It shouldn't specifically require a virtual environment, but it does require the package actually be installed using the normal tools.